# How to set first toggle always open and then close when click to second one

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, frontend

I have implemented a toggle accordion menu with jquery but having some issue to setting first one always open.

Right now all toggles are closed and works well when onclick but need some help to show the first one always open.

Here is jquery

```
var togg = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-toggle-menu-panel");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < togg.length; i++) {
 togg[i].onclick = function() {
  var active = document.querySelector(".mobile-toggle-menu-panel.active");
  if (active && active != this) {
   active.classList.remove("active");
}
  $(this).siblings(':not(.active)').removeClass('show');

  this.classList.toggle("active");
  this.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I have implemented a toggle accordion menu with jquery but having some
>   issue to setting first one always open.

For a long time it would have been conventional to use a class to indicate open or closed state:

- `class="open"`
- `class="closed"`

But in 2019, it's arguably better practice to use HTML5 custom `data-*` attributes to indicate state:

- `data-state="open"`
- `data-state="closed"`

To achieve the effect you are looking for, begin by giving the first accordion section a `data-state="open"` and each subsequent accordion section a `data-state="closed"`.

**Working Example:**

```js
const list = document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0];
const listItems = [... list.getElementsByClassName('list-item')];

const openListItem = (e) => {

  listItems.forEach((listItem) => listItem.dataset.state = 'closed');
  e.target.dataset.state = 'open';
}

list.addEventListener('click', openListItem, false);
```

```css
.list {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

.list-item {
  padding: 12px 0 0 12px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(191, 0, 0);
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(223, 0, 0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(127, 0, 0);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.2s linear, height 0.3s linear;
}

li:first-of-type {
  border-top: none;
}

li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.list-item:hover,
.list-item[data-state="open"] {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgb(207, 0, 0);
  text-shadow: 0 0 12px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
}

.list-item p {
  position: relative;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  margin: 12px 0 0 -12px;
  padding: 0 0 0 12px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 191, 191);
  text-transform: initial;
}

.list-item:hover p {
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.list-item[data-state="open"]{
  height: 66px;
}

.list-item[data-state="closed"]{
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">

<li class="list-item" data-state="open">
Item One
<p>Item One Paragraph</p>
</li>

<li class="list-item" data-state="closed">
Item Two
<p>Item Two Paragraph</p>
</li>

<li class="list-item" data-state="closed">
Item Three
<p>Item Three Paragraph</p>
</li>

<li class="list-item" data-state="closed">
Item Four
<p>Item Four Paragraph</p>
</li>

<li class="list-item" data-state="closed">
Item Five
<p>Item Five Paragraph</p>
</li>
</ul>
```